# Android ListView click set all Checkboxs to enabled

Tags: android, android-listview

i am facing a strange behavior in my android ListView: I have disabled checkboxes in each row. When I click on a row it seems that the checkboxes go back to enable for a short time before launching the next activity (the result of a click).

Here are the previous click and the after click : 
[image: Before click]
[image: Just after click]

**stationsfavoritesadapter.xml**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/listviewborder">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/favorite_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/starStyle"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:enabled="false"

            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/weatherimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/favorite_checkbox"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/StationNameText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/weatherimage"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/weatherimage"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temperatureText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/weatherimage"
            android:layout_below="@id/StationNameText"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trailsText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/StationNameText"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            />



    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the adapter class with the `getView()` method :

```
    public class StationsFavoritesAdapter extends StationsAdapter{

    public StationsFavoritesAdapter(StationsManager stations)
    {
        _stationManager = stations;
        _data = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Station>>();
        _data.addAll(_stationManager.GetFavorites().entrySet());

        _stationFilterList = _data;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final View result;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            result = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.stationsfavoritesadapter, parent, false);
        }
        else
        {
            result = convertView;
        }

        final Map.Entry<String, Station> station = getItem(position);

        ((TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.temperatureText)).setText(station.getValue().get_temperature() + "°C");
        ((TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.StationNameText)).setText(station.getKey());
        ((TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.trailsText)).setText(station.getValue().get_trails().first + "/" + station.getValue().get_trails().second);

        CheckBox favoriteBox = (CheckBox)result.findViewById(R.id.favorite_checkbox);

        favoriteBox.setChecked(true);


        ImageView image = (ImageView)result.findViewById(R.id.weatherimage);

        if(station.getValue().get_weather().equals("sunny"))
        {
            image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.sunnyicon);
        }
        else if(station.getValue().get_weather().equals("storm-clouds"))
        {
            image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.snowicon);
        }
        else
        {
            image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.cloudyicon);
        }

        return result;
    }


}
```

And the ListView click event :

```
    @Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View w, int position, long id)
{
    String stationName = adapter.getItem(position).getKey();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, StationActivity.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("Station name", stationName);
    intent.putExtras(b);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't understand what your program does and what you want to achieve. Can you explain me your idea, please?

Comment: I have a listview in an activity, each row contains a disabled checkbox. When I click on one row it seems that the checkboxes get enabled for a short time (Their color change). Why are they enabled when I just click in my list view row.

Comment: Can you give me a very very little sample of the ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Station>>() you use to fill the list? Just a little sample

Comment: I have added pictures it should be more clear. The array list contains station object but it should not be useful here.

Comment: Ok, but you are enabling intentionally the checkboxes when you call `favoriteBox.setChecked(true)`

Comment: I tried :   
        favoriteBox.setEnabled(false);
        favoriteBox.setChecked(true);
        favoriteBox.setEnabled(false);
Same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76396/discussion-between-joaquin-and-user1594047).

Answer (score 0):

Your getView functions gets called eveytime  the app is draws the list view.  I think what you want to do is do a onclicklistener on your list view then set the check box to true there, not in the getview

Use this code in your activity or fragment

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new. OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {



                }
            });
```

Comment: no the box should always be checked and I have check while debugging getView is not called after the click. So the click should not change the checkbox enabled state.

Comment: Why is this in your  getView. favoriteBox.setChecked(true);

Comment: I want them to always be true and disable. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the checkbox to disabled from within your getView method in the adapter, after you have checked the box:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    CheckBox favoriteBox =(CheckBox)result.findViewById(R.id.favorite_checkbox);

    favoriteBox.setChecked(true);
    favoriteBox.setEnabled(false);
```